# Dynamic height of modal with iframe inside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, modal-dialog

I have an iframe inside a bootstrap modal..
The iframe contents are dynamic..i.e. height is variable.
How can the modal automatically adjust height ?

```
<div class='modal fade my_modal' id='day_summary'>
<div class='container' style= 'width:100%; max-height:700px; overflow-y: visible';
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-8 col-centered'>
<iframe id = "f1" src= 'http://abcd.php' style="max-height:700px; overflow-y: visible; width:100%; float:center;"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- close search for service modal -->
```